# My bargraph lines are overlapping and x-Axis not in order my date values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

[image: My Graph]

```
$scope.options = {
         chart: {
             type: 'historicalBarChart',
             height: 450,
             margin : {
                 top: 30,
                 right: 30,
                 bottom: 65,
                 left: 80
             },
             x: function(d){return d[0];},
             y: function(d){return d[1]/10;},
             showValues: true,
             valueFormat: function(d){
                 return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
             },
             duration: 100,
             xAxis: {
                 axisLabel: 'X Axis',
                 axisLabelDistance: 10,
                 tickFormat: function(d) {
                     return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d))
                 },
                 rotateLabels: 30,
                 showMaxMin: false
             },
             yAxis: {
                 axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                 axisLabelDistance: -10,
                 tickFormat: function(d){
                     return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
                 }
             },
             tooltip: {
                 keyFormatter: function(d) {
                     return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d));
                 }
             },
             zoom: {
                 enabled: true,
                 scaleExtent: [1, 10],
                 useFixedDomain: false,
                 useNiceScale: false,
                 horizontalOff: false,
                 verticalOff: true,
                 unzoomEventType: 'dblclick.zoom'
             }
         }
     };

     $scope.data = [
         {
             "key" : "Quantity" ,
             "bar": true,
             "values" : [ [ null , null] , [ null ,null] , [ null , null] , [ null,null] , [ null,null] ]
         }];
     console.log($scope.data);
     $http.get('/getTotalInvoiceBydate').success(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
         for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++)
         {
             $scope.data[0].values[i][0]=Date.parse(response[i].invoice_date);
             $scope.data[0].values[i][1]=response[i].invoice_total;
         }

         // console.log($scope.data[0].values[0][0]);
     });

 });
```

Comment: create a plunker for your issue

Comment: cannot create plunker..because data came from database..trying to map the data to values then came the issue here